# Razor syntax to open explorer window

Tags: windows, razor, explorer, webmatrix

Noob here:

I'd like to have clickable link in Razor to open an explorer window on client machine when passed the appropriate path.  I'm new to the syntax (and limitations), but it's all internal, so I can resolve any security issues (if relevant).

Alternatively, advice on a (very) easy to install free control is also welcomed.  :)

Comment: That must be done on the client machine; it has nothing to do with Razor.  Also, it's impossible.

Comment: I doubt that it's impossible.

Comment: Without writing a browser plugin, this is impossible on modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In IE6, you should be able to write  `<a href="file://c:\whatever>...</a>`.
I don't think that will work on any other browser.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works in IE8 and IE9.  We use a mapped drive for an internal app.

Comment: @Knox: What zone are you coming from? What are your security settings?

Comment: The client machines have a P drive that is mapped to a server machine.  So the client has full privileges to directly access the files natively without any browser.  The link simply opens a Windows Explorer window to the files.  We're not serving the files through http, but rather directly through file sharing.  Nothing is special about security settings or the zone.  In @Slaks example, the C drive being referred to is the client C drive, not the server's C drive.

Comment: @Knox: What zone is the link in?

Comment: I was wrong about the security settings.  You will get a warning in IE9 if the base website is not in the "Trusted Sites" list.  I think I wouldn't need that if my website was in the "intranet" site, which is set to automatically detect.  It's not automatically detecting in my case.